# Cannot debug Swift module/framework embedded in Objective-C app

Tags: xcode, lldb, swift3, xcode8, swift2

> ## Alternative titles (to aid searching)
>
> - Cannot debug Swift 2.3 framework linked to an Objective-C app in Xcode 8
> - `error in auto-import: failed to get module 'XYZ' from AST context` Xcode 8
> - Xcode 8 cannot debug Swift framework
> - `warning: Swift error in module <XYZ>`
> - Workaround for; Xcode Debugger cannot debug apps written in Objective-C only but that link against frameworks written in Swift only. (28312362)

I have an app written in Objective-C that links against some modules (frameworks) written in Swift 2.x.

## Question

Everything (debugging etc.) works fine in [xcode7](/questions/tagged/xcode7), however when moving to [xcode8](/questions/tagged/xcode8) and updating the modules to use [swift2.3](/questions/tagged/swift2.3) I was unable to debug the modules.

LLDB reported these errors:

```
warning: Swift error in module XYZ.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

error: in auto-import:
failed to get module 'ABC' from AST context
```

This does not happen if I link the modules to an app built in Swift 2.3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## tl:dr

Add a user defined setting under "Build Settings" for your app target.

`SWIFT_VERSION = 2.3`

[image: SWIFT_VERSION = 2.3 — Build Settings]

## More Info

I'm unsure if this is an Xcode 8 bug or if it's Apple policy (to try an force developers to Swift 3.0?). But... by default Xcode 8 installs the Swift 3.0 versions of the standard Swift runtime libraries.

When it comes to debugging with LLDM the Swift 2.3 modules fail to load (in to the Swift 3.0 runtime).

Forcing the app to use Swift 2.3 (or legacy Swift as Apple call it), fixes the issue.

Swift apps have this setting exposed by Xcode but you have to manually add it for an Objective-C app.

## Further Advice

Port your Swift 2.3 code to Swift 3.0 as soon as possible, Apple won't support 2.x for very long.

Comment: Xcode 8.0 will try to determine which version of Swift you are using and choose the appropriate toolchain.  Something in how your project is set up is defeating that detection.

For instance, Xcode will choose the latest toolchain available, which happens to also be the Swift 3.0 one, for a pure ObjC project.  Maybe, for instance, Xcode isn't looking through dependent sub-projects or targets of pure ObjC targets to see if there is any Swift around in them?

That seems worth filing a bug about.

Comment: This isn't working for us, for some reason. Explicitly setting a `swift_version` (labelled in 8A218a as "Use Legacy Swift Language Version") doesn't affect the results.

Comment: @DavidLord "Use Legacy Swift Language Version" is different, this is used to tell Xcode you want to use Swift 2.x and not 3.x, in the above scenario this would be set on the Framework target. `SWIFT_VERSION` should be set on the (Objective-C) app target. Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah - indeed! So much of the problem you've described applies to our pure Swift project, but we have no Obj-C linking in Swift modules. Thanks for the Q&A, will keep experimenting (or do without LLDB until we move to Swift 3).

Comment: The "error in auto-import" thing is probably a general diagnostic that could represent any number of different errors.  I'm getting the same error, but not the message that tells me *which* module is causing it, leading me to suspect it's a different issue altogether.  And I've double-checked that swift_version is set correctly.

Comment: `There already is another setting named "SWIFT_VERSION". Please enter a different name.`

Answer (score 19):

For me it was just as simple as it was painful and time consuming:

`import SDWebImage` **was the PROBLEM**, 
because one of the frameworks had the SDWebImage already packed in it(and I couldn't see it), and that framework happened to be Objective-C, and the app was Swift. 
I also added the SDWebImage to the project, because I use it in the classes I write, and that what created the mess the Xcode debugger couldn't deal with. 
So basically, make sure you don't have ANYTHING duplicated in ANY way, I'd check for common things like SDWebImage for example.

Comment: I had the exact same issue, thanks for pointing towards this.

Comment: @Tim Friedland same problem with JSON model framework thanks for the answer

Comment: yes perfect answer.. save my lots of time. thanks @Tim Friedland

Comment: In my case, I was using SDWebImage as well as FirebaseUI (which depends on SDWebImage) and importing both in Swift. Moving these imports to my bridging header solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 11):

use **fr v** instead **po** for debugging

For more debugging 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181358/Debugging-with-Xcode

Comment: `fr v` stands for "frame variable". More info is available at the [LLDB Debugging Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/lldb-guide/chapters/C5-Examining-The-Call-Stack.html)

Comment: Seems like not a solution since frame variables anyway you can see on left panel of your console which doesn't have all necessary output.

Answer (score 9):

I discussed this issue with an Apple engineer named Sean at WWDC 2017.

My team spent weeks trying to figure this out, and it ended up being a bug on Apple's compiler, which we could never have figured out by ourselves. Also, it has a VERY easy workaround.

There happens to be a bug with the way the compiling flags get aggregated from the frameworks and the project, and the "pure Objective-C" project "activates" it.

Solution: add one single, empty Swift file ("Whatever.swift", or whatever) in your Objective-C project, making it not-pure-objective-c anymore  (new->file->Swift file, don't create the bridging header. The file will only contain the import of Foundation).

And that's it. Problem solved.

Comment: Do you happen to have a rdar or Swift bug number associated with this?

Comment: To fix debugging for a project with only tests in Swift, you still need to add an empty Swift that targets the project.  Adding just the Swift test file is not enough.  In case anyone else comes across this solution and is only wanting to write tests in Swift.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to remove `Objective-C Bridging header` from build settings file. My Bridging header file did not do anything.. so it was okay.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the `error in auto-import: failed to get module 'XYZ' from AST context` message while attempting to debug in an 9.3 simulator. Switching to a 10.2 simulator resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this when building a framework with Carthage. Trying to debug would print the error, which referenced an Obj-C framework dependency.

I found this [blog post](https://indiestack.com/2017/04/debugging-swift-error-in-auto-import/) which suggested adding a the following user-defined build setting to my project:

For Debug: `REMOVE_HEADERS_FROM_EMBEDDED_BUNDLES = NO`

For Release: `REMOVE_HEADERS_FROM_EMBEDDED_BUNDLES = YES`

This fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart Xcode. In my case it resolved an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a compiler error in the "C" code which was reported in LLDB, after fixing the error LLDB started working again.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Tim https://stackoverflow.com/a/41876400/1840269 the root cause to our problem was a matter of duplicates.

We had a obj-c wrapper category for SDWebImage that was used from both obj-c and Swift.
When Importing the category from Swift everything blew up because of redefinition/duplicate import since the SDWebImage pod already exposed it self as a Swift module.

The solution? We re-implemented the obj-c category as a Swift extension - and kept using it from both Swift and obj-c by adding `@objc` in front of the extension and importing the `#import "product-Swift.h"` file from obj-c.

And maybe start with checking: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1947/_index.html.

Answer (score 0):

I just took 2 days for me to resolve and debugging through print command all the time. Now I got the issue:

My project is in Swift and I was using objective-C library same as imported in pods for swift(old Objective-C project merged in this one) and was using import IQKeyboardManager as well as import "IQKeyboardManager.h" header as well. That conflicts and deleting the header one resolved my issue finally.
You can check with this type of duplicity in libraries.