# warning: Swift error in module. Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift3, lldb

I have no debugging values in my console for my swift + obj-c app, and I get a really unhelpful message that explains why the debugger isn't working: "warning: Swift error in module XXX.". XXX is the name of my module, not a 3rd party that I include.

My app has been around since before Swift. I used the bridging header to start using Swift, and I recently used the Xcode tool to migrate all the Swift 2 files to Swift 3. (but I still have obj-c legacy in there). I use cocoapods, which may be contributing to the problem.

[image: no debugger information...]

```
(lldb) po self
warning: Swift error in module XXX.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.
```

I tried following the second answer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39467654/cannot-debug-swift-module-framework-embedded-in-objective-c-app) and a couple others
I have found that suggest the same thing: remove duplicate imports.

I tried removing duplicate imports from my swift project. In fact if I run `find . -name "*swift" | xargs grep "import"` I get no results. So I went to the extreme of removing all imports from all of my swift files (and commenting out code to get it to compile) just to see if I can get my debugger to come back.

So...

- Is there another solution to this problem?
- Is there a way to get a more detailed error message?
- Is it a problem to have duplicate headers in the my bridging header? For example, a lot of my obj-c files import UIKit, and I include a few of those files in the bridging header.

Answer (score 1):

Just now I have encountered this problem.
This is my solution:

If you import 3rd repo by Cocoapods, and the repo is written by Objective-C, you need to import it by this way:

```
// System 
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

// Directly add - Objective-C
#import "EaseUI.h"

// Cocoapods - Objcetive-C
@import MJRefresh;
```

You can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues/313) in Github and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31219422/swift-debugger-does-not-show-variable-values-when-importing-objc-framework/31455774#31455774).

Comment: Don't even know how to thank you! This is the solution!

Comment: This isn't a complete solution since it leaves out how to solve the problem if the offending module is written in Swift.