# error: in auto-import: failed to get module from AST context:

Tags: ios, openssl, cocoapods

I installed OpenSSL via CocoaPods and it all works fine, except now I can not use PO in the debugger to view variables at a breakpoint.  Below is output from a sample program I was learning from.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  This is a swift 4 project.  I follow the instructions from this tutorial:

[Local Receipt Validation for iOS in Swift From Start to Finish](https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2017/08/01/local-receipt-validation-swift-start-finish/)

```
(lldb) po self
```

warning: Swift error in module SwiftyLocalReceiptValidatorDemo.
Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.

error: in auto-import:

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44290557/warning-swift-error-in-module-debug-info-from-this-module-will-be-unavailable

Comment: This does not help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure out a work around from this article:

[Validating In-App Purchase Receipts Locally in Swift!](https://baglabs.com/2015/09/17/validating-in-app-purchase-receipts-locally-in-swift/)

Turns out if I comment out the line:

```
int (*rsa_mod_exp) (BIGNUM *r0, const BIGNUM *I, RSA *rsa, BN_CTX *ctx);
```

in the rsa.h header file, the issues with using PO to view variables is gone.

Comment: Just make sure you clean and rebuild the project after doing this!